# Vim search replace all files in current (project) folder

Tags: search, macvim

One of the open questions I have about Vim is if there is a way to perform a search/replace in the current project (bear with me if I use this notion inherited from other editors).

For instance, let's assume I want to search my project files for a method name, and rename all the instances of that method call.

This is how I can proceed with Sublime.

[image]

How would you do this in Vim (possibly MacVim) without relying on other programs such as `ack` or `sed`?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There are several ways to do this.

#### Inside Current Directory

If you want to perform the search/replace in a project tree, you can use Vim's [argument list](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#argument-list).

Simply open Vim and then use the `:args` command to populate the argument list. You can pass in multiple filenames or even globs.

For example, `:args **/*.rb` will recursively search the current directory for ruby files. Notice that this is also like opening Vim with `vim **/*.rb`. You can even use the shell's `find` command to get a list of all files in the current directory by running:

```
:args `find . -type f`
```

You can view the current args list by running `:args` by itself. If you want to add or delete files from the list, you can use the `:argadd` or the `:argdelete` commands respectively.

Once you're happy with the list, now you can use Vim's powerful [`:argdo`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdo) command which runs a command for every file in the argument list: `:argdo %s/search/replace/g`

Here are some tips for searching (based on some of the comments):

1. Use a word boundary if you wanted to search for "foo" but not "foo_bar". Use the `\<` and `\>` constructs around the search pattern like so: `:argdo %s/\<search\>/foobar/g`
2. Use a `/c` search flag if you want Vim to ask for confirmation before replacing a search term.
3. Use a `/e` search flag if you want to skip the "pattern not found" errors.
4. You can also choose to save the file after performing the search: `:argdo %s/search/replace/g | update`. Here, `:update` is used because it will only save the file if it has changed.

#### Open buffers

If you already have buffers open you want to do the search/replace on, you can use `:bufdo`, which runs a command for every file in your buffer list (`:ls`).

The command is very similar to `:argdo`:  `:bufdo %s/search/replace/g`

Similar to `:argdo` and `:bufdo`, there is `:windo` and `:tabdo` that act on windows and tabs respectively. They are less often used but still useful to know.

Comment: It could probably be a good idea to use the `/c` flag for confirming substitutions.

Comment: I would also recommend using word boundaries `\<` and `\>` around the `search` to avoid partial word replacements.

Comment: One other comment is that vim's working directory is by default where you started vim, not the current file's directory. You can set the working directory to the current file using ```:cd %:p:h```. Other working directory options are listed in http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Set_working_directory_to_the_current_file.

Answer (score 97):

Let's say we have a simple project structure like this:

[image]

`greeting.txt` looks like

[image]

and `info/age.txt` looks like

[image]

Let's say we want to replace all occurrences of `Sam` with `Bob`. Here's what we would do:

## 1. **Set working directory**

Make sure Vim's current working directory is the root of the project:

```
     :cd {path to root directory}
```

You can use `:pwd` to print the current working directory and ensure that it is
correct.

## 2. **Find files that contain 'Sam'**

Use Vim's `:vimgrep` command to search for all occurrences of `Sam` within the project:

```
    :vimgrep /Sam/gj **/*
```

#### Notes:

- `Sam` is the search "pattern" sandwiched between two forward slashes
- The `**/*` says to search in all files recursively
- The `g` flag says to search for all occurrences in each line (this is actually overkill here, but it does not hurt either)
- The `j` flag prevents vim from automatically jumping to the first match

This will populate the quickfix list with all instances of `Sam`.  If you want to view  the quickfix list, you can use the Vim command `:copen`

[image]

## 3. **Substitute within all files that contain 'Sam'**

Now we want to run Vim's `:substitute` command inside every file in the quickfix list. We can do this using the `:cfdo {cmd}` command which executes `{cmd}` in each file in the quickfix list. The specific `{cmd}` we want to use is `:substitute` or `:s` for short. Adding the `update` command at the end ensures that each file is saved before moving on to the next one (this is necessary if you don't `:set hidden`). The full line would look like:

```
    :cfdo %s/Sam/Bob/gc | update
```

If you do `:set hidden`, you can optionally leave off `| update`, and then do `:cfdo update` or `:wall`.

#### Notes:

- The `%` is a line range that specifies *every* line
- The `g` flag says to substitute *all* occurrences in each line
- The `c` flag causes vim to ask you to confirm each replacement individually
  (you might want to leave this out)

Comment: I like this more. It's simple, and works with Ack (or any plugin that populates the QuickFix window).

Comment: This is a great answer

Comment: Was getting "no write since last change", doing `cfdo %s/Sam/Bob/g | update` fixed that for me

Comment: @hakunin I'd recommend setting the `hidden` option with `:set hidden` if you haven't already done so.

Comment: This is more portable answer, works in any OS.

Comment: if you do a search for the word to change first with `/Sam`, it get highlighted. In later searches you'd use `//...` instead to repeat the previous search, like `:vimgrep //gj **/*` and `:cfdo %s//Bob/gc | update`.

Answer (score 3):

Although not a VIM solution, if you are using VI/VIM you might find it easier to use a CLI solution. To change all files in the current directory, use `perl` as it was made for situations like this:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' *
```

If you need to do it in subdirectories too, I usually pair `perl` with `find`:

```
$ find . -name '*' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

The nice thing about this is that you can easily further refine the list to specific file types. For instance, to restrict to python files:

```
$ perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g' *.py
$ find . -name '*.py' -print0 | xargs -0 perl -pi -e 's/foo/bar/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace phrase with another one, you can use Vim Ex mode.

For example (`ex` is alias to `vim -E`):

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo!%s/foo/bar/g' -cxa *.*
```

Recursively in bash/zsh (with `globstar` set, e.g. `shopt -s globstar`):

```
$ ex -s +'bufdo!%s/foo/bar/g' -cxa **/*.*
$ ex -s +'n **/*.*' +'bufdo!%s/foo/bar/g' -cxa
```

Recursively (using `find` and ignore hidden files such as `.git` files):

```
$ find . -type f -not -path '*/\.*' -exec ex -s +'bufdo!%s/foo/bar/g' -cxa {} "+"
```

<sup>Note: The `:bufdo` command is not [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html).</sup>

<sup>Note: Syntax `-not -path '*/\.*'` is used to ignore hidden files (such as `.git`).</sup>

Comment: note bufdo is not POSIX http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/ex.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the shell command using `find` and `ex` editor (without [using `:bufdo`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2998/467)):

```
find . -name '*.rb' -exec ex +'%s/foo/bar/ge' -V1 -scwq! {} ';'
```

This will edit in-place all `*.rb` files in the current folder (recursively) and replace `foo` with `bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Base on https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/10310
[image]

```
    com!  -nargs=+   Fr    call Find_replacE(<f-args>)
        fun! Find_replacE(old_s, new_s)
            execute 'vimgrep' '@'..a:old_s..'@gj' '**/*'
            execute 'cfdo % sub@'..a:old_s..'@'..a:new_s..'@gc  | update '
        endf
```

Comment: Instead of hardcoding the @ separator, consider using the escape function to escape the separator or taking the pattern with delimiters