# Function That Substitutes Across Multiple Files

Tags: vimrc, substitute, functions, quickfix, vimgrep

I'm trying to create a function that implements the functionality outlined here: [Vim search replace all files in current (project) folder](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2776/vim-search-replace-all-files-in-current-project-folder)

My current attempt:

```
nnoremap <C-F> :call ReplaceAcrossAllFiles(
function! ReplaceAcrossAllFiles(search, replace)
  execute "vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj | copen "
    \ . " | cfdo %s/" a:search . "/" . a:replace . "/gc"
    \ . " | cfdo update"
endfunction
```

If, for example, I execute `ReplaceAcrossAllFiles("hi", "hello")` I get `E683: File name missing or invalid parameter`

**EDIT**

Thank you @Garcys and @statox for your answers.
I now get an error which I believe is related to the quickfix window: `E553: No more items`. I'm able to suppress this with:
`silent execute "vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj **/* | copen"`. However, as soon as I jump to the first match in another file, the error comes up again, cancelling the rest of the substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
nnoremap <S-F> :vimgrep //gj **/* <bar> copen<C-B><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right><Right>
nnoremap <C-F> :call ReplaceAcrossAllFiles(
function! ReplaceAcrossAllFiles(search, replace)
  silent! execute "vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj **/* | copen"
  silent! execute  "cfdo %s/" . a:search . "/" . a:replace . "/gc"
  silent! cfdo update
endfunction
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing something. After looking up the vimgrep documentation (`:h vimgrep`) you need the file(s).

```
vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj **/*
```

The new script could be like this:

```
function! ReplaceAcrossAllFiles(search, replace)
  execute "vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj **/* | copen "
  execute "cfdo %s/" a:search . "/" . a:replace . "/g | cfdo update"
endfunction
```

Some options should be reviewed.

Comment: I think you forgot to add the `**/*` in the new script :)

Comment: Thank @statox for the error !!

Answer (score 3):

If you replace `execute` by `echo` in your function you'll see that the executed command is

```
vimgrep /hi/gj | copen  | cfdo %s/ hi/hello/gc | cfdo update
```

But [`:h :vimgrep`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#%3Avimgrep) says that the command must be called with a filename :

```
:vim[grep][!] /{pattern}/[g][j] {file}
```

That's why `vimgrep /hi/gj` triggers a missing file name error.

You need to could add `**/*` as a filename to match all files in your directory like this:

```
execute "vimgrep /" . a:search . "/gj **/* | copen "
```